# Alternative time.sleep() in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I was trying to make a game with Tkinter, but keeps crashing because of `time.sleep()`, because it makes the window sleep so it doesn't refresh.

I tried searching for "Tkinter window crashing from time.sleep" and only found 1 question with -9 votes.

Is there an alternative of `time.sleep()`? I'm currently new to Python and stack overflow.
If there is so, please answer.

and Thanks for helping me!

Comment: what are you trying to solve using time.sleep() ? why would you make the user wait for your game?

Comment: I'm making a reaction test game, where the user will press a start button and shows a green image. And after a random seconds, a red image will appear and the user have to press spacebar as fast as they can. But it just freezes when i pressed the start button

Comment: You should add your whole code and clarify the question

Comment: You need to use tkinters `after` method. You can see an example where I use it in this reply: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65231089/python-how-do-i-make-a-fast-reaction-test-with-tkinter/65231501#65231501

Comment: @oskros but its for a function?

Comment: Yes, thats the way it works. In your case the delay would be a random number of milliseconds, and the function would be generating the red image and activating the space hotkey the user should press.

Comment: It is hard to tell how to do without any code.

Comment: well that was a coincidence that guy made a fast reaction too with green and red images, but thank you for your answer. It works!

Comment: If you search for `[tkinter] time.sleep is:question` you will get over 1500 results.

Comment: @Ruli: we don't want the _whole_ code. We need a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Preface: I am not familiar with Tkinter, but the following information will apply to *all* GUI applications, so I hope it's helpful.

The core of any GUI application is the [main event loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop). This is a continuous loop that gathers user input such as keyboard presses or mouse clicks, and then draws an image to the screen. If your program fails to process events quickly, Windows will show an error message like the following:

[image: Screenshot of "X is not responding" dialog]

This means your program can never sleep for more than a second or so. The solution is to rewrite the program to only sleep for very short time periods. Consider the following program:

```
reaction_time = 0
current_image = "screen1.jpg"
delay = get_random_number_of_milliseconds()

# Main event loop:
while True:
    key = get_keypress()

    if delay < 0:
        current_image = "screen2.jpg"
        if key == ENTER:
            print("Your reaction time was:", reaction_time)
            exit()
        else:
            reaction_time = reaction_time + 100
    else:
        delay = delay - 100

    draw_image_to_screen(current_image)
    sleep(0.1)
```

As you can see, this program decrements the value of `delay` each loop by 100 milliseconds, and then calls `sleep(0.1)` which will sleep for approximately 0.1 seconds.

Image that `screen1.jpg` contains a blank image and `screen2.jpg` contains a red circle. This program would first wait for a random time, then start incrementing the `reaction_time` variable as soon as the red circle is shown, and exit when the user presses `Enter`.

Comment: sorry for late respond, but where does `get_random_number_of_milliseconds` come from? a module?

Comment: It's just an example, as are the other functions. It's up to you to provide their implementations :)